# How would you go about solving this difficult physics problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

[image]

[image]

I was able to calculate an angular frequency of 85.4357 rad/s for this mass. However, I am confused as to what to do next. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two unknowns $A$ and $\phi_o$ so you need two equations.

You are given the displacement $y$ at $t=0$ which gives you one of the equations.

If you differentiate the equation for the displacement $y$ with respect to time $t$  this will give you an expression for the velocity which is you second equation.